# How to get a specific font size in baposter?

Tags: fontsize, posters, baposter

I am trying to create a poster with font size of 12pt. What should be the value of `fontscale`?

```
\documentclass[landscape,paperwidth=22in,paperheight=28in,fontscale=?]{baposter}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0.83`. I think.

What `baposter` seems to do is to set the paper width to `paperwidth x fontscale`, as supplied in the class options, and similar for the height. It then scales the page up again (with help from `pgfpages`) to the defined paper size. As the base class is `article`, which uses 10pt as the default, you need 10pt/12pt ≈ 0.83 for `fontscale`.

```
\documentclass[paperwidth=22in,paperheight=28in,fontscale=0.833]{baposter}
\begin{document}
Foobar
\end{document}
```

Here is an attempt at a comparison with `article`. The different *Foobar*s are from screenshots at the same magnification.

[image]

Comment: You mean I should get font size 10pt with fontscale=1? right?

Comment: @D_B I think you have a strange definition of huge. See image I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the values of `fontscale` should be and don't have the class `baposter` on my machine (and it isn't on CTAN).

But you can choose arbitrary fontsizes using `\fontsize{<fontsize>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont` provided that you use a scalable font (like e.g. `lmodern` or `helvet`).

Comment: But it seems that the result from \fontsize also depends on fontscale. I mean with different fontscales, I get different sizes even if \fontsize{12pt}{14.4}\selectfont is kept there.

Comment: @D_B Of course it depends on fontscale, as I said in my answer, the poster is first made with a smaller papersize (depending on fontscale), and then scaled up afterwards.